# Addition from a csv column in java: how do I reset variable total?

Tags: java, csv, math

As the title says, I'm trying to get 3 separate to totals-one per empID-and a grandTotal;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class SalesReport{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        File f = new File("sales.csv");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        int empID = 0;
        double sales = 0.0;
        double total = 0.0;
        double allTotal = 0.0;
        System.out.println("Brewster's Used Cars, Inc.\nSales Report\n\nSalesperson ID\t\tSales Amount");
        for(int i = 0;i<43;i++){
            System.out.print("≡");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String data = in.next();
            String[] field = data.split(",");
            sales = Double.parseDouble(field[1]);
            if(empID == 0){
                empID = Integer.parseInt(field[0]);
            }
            if(Integer.parseInt(field[0])!=empID){
                System.out.printf("Total sales for this salesperson: $%,3.2f\n", total);
                empID = Integer.parseInt(field[0]);
                total += sales;
            }
            else{
                total += sales;
            }
            System.out.printf(empID + "\t\t\t$%,3.2f\n", sales);
        }
        allTotal += total;
        System.out.printf("Total sales for this salesperson: $%,3.2f\n", total);
        System.out.printf("Total of all sales: $%,3.2f\n", allTotal);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

this outputs:

```
Brewster's Used Cars, Inc.
Sales Report

Salesperson ID          Sales Amount
≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡
100                     $10,000.00
100                     $12,000.00
100                     $5,000.00
Total sales for this salesperson: $27,000.00
101                     $14,000.00
101                     $18,000.00
101                     $12,500.00
Total sales for this salesperson: $71,500.00
102                     $13,500.00
102                     $14,500.00
102                     $20,000.00
Total sales for this salesperson: $119,500.00
Total of all sales: $119,500.00.
```

My attempt of adding `total = 0.0;` to the second if statement turns the first 2 totals into 0, though the 3rd is correct. So the question is, how do I get this hunk of code to calculate the individual's totals and the grand total of sales?

Comment: spacing and new lines ARE correct in the output, don't know why I can't put it as such here.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a couple of sample lines from file _sales.csv_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second if (that reads `if(Integer.parseInt(field[0])!=empID)`), try setting `total = sales` instead of `total += sales` as it is now.

In Java, use `=` to assign a value to a variable, and use `+=` to add on an additional value to an existing variable.

Comment: hmm, that corrected employee totals, but now the grand total is equal to the final employee total. I thank you for helping me in that aspect. I changed the allTotal to += sales instead, then moved into the while loop, now it works as intended, thank you again